# SQLite Database not creating in avd

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a begginer in android and trying to create a database for last five days and I have tried a lot but still I am not able to create database in the AVD. I have referred a lot about database and I tried a lot but I can't find bug and also please check my table creation code. I am thanking to advance for your time and help. Here is my code..

```
package com.example.kannan.football_manager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by kannan on 25/1/16.
 */
public class Admin_Database_Operations extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final String ADMIN_DB="admin_info";
    public static final String ADMIN_TB="abmin_table";
    public static final String ADMIN_NAME="admin_name";
    public static final String ADMIN_PASS="admin_pass";
    public static  final String ADMIN_ID="admin_id";

    public  static final  int database_version=1;

    //creating database

    public Admin_Database_Operations(Context c)
    {
        super(c, ADMIN_DB, null, database_version);
        Log.d("database creation", "database created");
       // SQLiteDatabase sq=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }





    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqls) {

        Log.d("Checking oncreate","Entered OnCreate");

        //String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ADMIN_TB + "(" + ADMIN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ ADMIN_NAME
            //    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ADMIN_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL " + ")";

        String str_tbl="CREATE TABLE "+ ADMIN_TB +"(admin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,admin_name TEXT NOT NULL,admin_pass TEXT NOT NULL)";

        Log.i("createDB=",str_tbl);

        Log.d("Table creatiion", "Table Query executing");

        try {
            sqls.execSQL(str_tbl);
            Log.d("Table creation ", "TABLE CREATED ");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }




    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqls, int i, int i1)
    {

        String Drop="DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+ADMIN_TB;
        sqls.execSQL(Drop);
        onCreate(sqls);
    }


    public void putInformation(Admin_Database_Operations ado,String name,String pass)
    {
        Log.d("Entering class","Entered class");

        SQLiteDatabase sq=ado.getWritableDatabase();


        Log.d("Creating  database","Database created");
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put(ADMIN_NAME,name);
        cv.put(ADMIN_PASS,pass);



        long k=sq.insert(ADMIN_TB,null,cv);
        sq.close();

    }
}

 package com.example.kannan.football_manager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button btn_Admin;
    public  Button btn_Cancel;
    public Button btn_Login;
    public Button btn_cngepsw;

    public EditText edttxt_name;
    public EditText edttxt_pass;

    public SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
    public Context ctx;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        //Declaring Nodes

      btn_Admin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Admin);
        btn_Cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);
        btn_Login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
        btn_cngepsw=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cngepsw);

        edttxt_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt_name);
        edttxt_pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt_pass);




        btn_Login.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        String name="kannan";
                        String pass="pass";
                        Admin_Database_Operations ado=new Admin_Database_Operations(ctx);

                        try {
                            //ado.onCreate(sqldb);
                            Log.d("Checking value",name);

                            Log.d("Entered to clss","trying to insert");
                            ado.putInformation(ado, name, pass);
                            Log.d("Checking value",name);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.d("Exception Catch", " ");
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            e.getMessage();
                        }




                        Log.d("Database operation", "INSERT ONE RAW");


                    }

                }

        );


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//Here is my locat error

02-04 10:21:39.010 1626-1626/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-04 10:21:39.140 1626-1632/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-04 10:21:39.290 1626-1626/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.kannan.football_manager is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-04 10:21:39.300 1626-1626/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
02-04 10:21:41.310 1626-1632/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
02-04 10:21:41.400 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: Debugger has connected
02-04 10:21:41.400 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:41.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:41.820 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:42.030 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:42.240 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:42.450 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:42.660 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:42.870 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:43.080 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:43.290 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-04 10:21:43.500 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/System.out: debugger has settled (1375)
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17969: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17973: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-04 10:21:43.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-04 10:21:43.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-04 10:21:43.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 423: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-04 10:21:43.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-04 10:21:43.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-04 10:21:43.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 445: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-04 10:21:43.610 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-04 10:21:43.670 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
02-04 10:21:43.670 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-04 10:21:43.680 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-04 10:21:43.680 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
02-04 10:21:43.680 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 388: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-04 10:21:43.680 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-04 10:21:44.070 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-04 10:21:44.110 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-04 10:21:44.160 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 232K, 10% free 3112K/3452K, paused 3ms, total 6ms
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/database creation: database created
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/Checking value: kannan
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/Entered to clss: trying to insert
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/Entering class: Entered class
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/Exception Catch:  
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at com.example.kannan.football_manager.Admin_Database_Operations.putInformation(Admin_Database_Operations.java:81)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at com.example.kannan.football_manager.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:61)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 10:22:00.550 1626-1626/com.example.kannan.football_manager D/Database operation: INSERT ONE RAW
```

Comment: exactly **HOW** is this not working?

Comment: `System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Instead of SQLiteDatabase sq=ado.getWritableDatabase(); , you should use SQLiteDatabase sq=this.getWritableDatabase(); and there's no need to pass your SQLHelper as a parameter on the putInformation() method